# pandas- return Month containing Max value for each year

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like:

```
Year Month Value
2017  1     100
2017  2      1
2017  4      2
2018  3      88
2018  4      8
2019  5      87
2019  6      1
```

I'd the dataframe to return the Month and Value for each year where the value is the maximum:

```
year  month  value
2017    1      100
2018    3      88
2019    5      87
```

I've attempted something like `df=df.groupby(["Year","Month"])['Value']).max()` however, it returns the full data set because each Year / Month pair is unique (i believe).

Comment: `df.sort_values('Value').drop_duplicates('Year',keep='last')`

Comment: The issue with `df.groupby(["Year","Month"])` is that your grouper now contains both Year and Month, meaning you got all unique groups (equal to the amount of rows).

Comment: Be careful though as a max-function might not get both values (if 2 year-month have same value).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the index where the top Value occurs with `.groupby(...).idxmax()` and use that to index into the original dataframe:

```
In [28]: df.loc[df.groupby("Year")["Value"].idxmax()]
Out[28]:
   Year  Month  Value
0  2017      1    100
3  2018      3     88
5  2019      5     87
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that also handles duplicate possibility:

```
m = df.groupby('Year')['Value'].transform('max') == df['Value']
dfmax = df.loc[m]
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
Year Month Value
2017  1     100
2017  2      1
2017  4      2
2018  3      88
2018  4      88
2019  5      87
2019  6      1'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+')
m = df.groupby('Year')['Value'].transform('max') == df['Value']
print(df[m])
```

---

```
   Year  Month  Value
0  2017      1    100
3  2018      3     88
4  2018      4     88
5  2019      5     87
```